# Block website users if their IP address resolves to a specific domain

Tags: asp.net, iis, dns

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544898/restricting-access-to-a-website-by-ip-address-range-domain) article, the answer points out that restricting access according to domain name means that the server has to perform DNS lookup for each request, which makes sense - this is not something you would want to do.

That being said, is there a way to reverse lookup all IP addresses that resolve to a domain, and all of its sub-domains? Thus compiling a list of IP addresses for which to block requests.

Is there a way of finding all these sub domains and then performing DNS lookup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Practically, no, there is no general way to find all the names in a zone. There may be ways for a particular zone, but it's fairly rare.

But then, this also looks a whole lot like an A-B question. You probably don't want to block anyone connecting from an IP that reverse-lookups to a particular domain name just for fun, you probably want to block people coming from some kind of organization or entity from connecting. So look up what IP ranges that organization/entity owns, and block those. No DNS needed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Calle, can you explain a bit more about looking up what IP ranges an organisation owns?

Comment: A whois query for an IP address usually says outright which range it's in and who owns that range. To try and find all ranges owned by a particular entity, try looking them up at the web site for the relevant [RIR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regional_Internet_registry). Or possibly all five RIRs, if it's a multinational corporation.